# Verifying Proxy contracts on EtherScan

Tags: etherscan, proxy-contracts

How one can verify a proxy contract, like OpenZeppelin Upgrade Proxy, on EtherScan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the writing of this, [EtherScan](https://etherscan.io) has added an option for verifying proxy contracts.

It can be found under `More Options` menu on the contract source code

[image: Example screenshot]

Comment: A note on this one: This will only work if the Proxy either implements one of the proxy standards, or if at least one transaction was executed via this proxy, so that Etherscan can figure out the address of the implementation contract.